# Python openweather, json - get weather by city name - how can I say that the city is incorrrect?

Tags: python, json, weather, weather-api

I found and modified simple code to get weather condition in Python using openweather and json format. But I have a problem - how can I say that the city is incorrect?

I mean even if I pass a wrong, nonexisting city, read always gives an answer (theres no such thing like 'empty response' or something like that).

See the code below to see what I'm talking about:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2, json

city = "etre4t5r5e4re" # the city name is incorrent
url = "http://openweathermap.org/data/2.1/forecast/city?q="
url += city
try :
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    info = wx.MessageBox(u"Internet connection error", u"Error", wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    info = wx.MessageBox(u"Internet connection error", u"Error", wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR)
except httplib.HTTPException, e:
    info = wx.MessageBox(u"Internet connection error", u"Error", wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR)
except Exception:
    info = wx.MessageBox(u"Error", u"Error", wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR)
weather = response.read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(weather) # it will show weather but thats not what I want for non-existing city!
```

Comment: The url `http://openweathermap.org/data/2.1/forecast/city?q=etre4t5r5e4re` returns `Internal Server Error Undefined index: geonames_id` for me.

Comment: When i am trying to get incorrect city info, the service gives me Moscow.

Comment: @NiclasNilsson: it's strange, cause I actually gets this output: http://pastebin.com/aa1q6DBK with no errors o_O

Comment: @alexvassel thanks for your answer too, very helpful. At least I know that not only I have wrong results with this script

Comment: @mazix: Really strange http://pastebin.com/LH8dATfL

Comment: @NiclasNilsson : did you try to do the same with my script (I mean, run it)? What results do you get with it? Could you please check?:)

Comment: I think that if you get smth rather that what you entered, this can be treated as no city.

Comment: @alexvassel : Changed the code: `city = str(raw_input("Pass your city:\n> "))` and no matter what I type, theres always an answer :/

Comment: @mazix Only running python2. I simplified it and ran it: http://pastebin.com/eTbfTGMY

Comment: @NiclasNilsson : thank you so much for that!:) So theres no such issue with Python3, interesting ... Do you have any idea how to deal with it in Python 2?

Comment: @mazix: I don't understand your question. You could deal with it like you have already done. With an exception. But have you tried fetching a town that does'nt exist in a  browser or with curl or something? Do you then get server error or json data?

Comment: @NiclasNilsson: I tried everything you tried: ran my script (got json data with incorrect city -.-), used curl, (the same result), opened generated url, lets say `http://openweathermap.org/data/2.1/forecast/city?q=rtkjrtjriotjeri` in webbrowser ---> every time I got json data, not the exception, thats why its very strange to me

Comment: @mazix It is indeed. I can't explain why we get diffrent results. We really should'nt...

Comment: You might find useful [my GitHub Python project PyOWM](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm), which is a simple object-oriented client wrapper around the Open Weather Map web API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a recurrent ID when the city requested doesn't exist, you can maybe based your code on that, or make a second request. I've explained the two solutions that I would have used.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib2, json

city = "etre4t5r5e4re"
root = "http://openweathermap.org/data/2.1/forecast/city?q=%s"
url  = root % city

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
j = json.load(response)

# Solution 1
if j.get('url', '').split('/')[-1] == '7284885':
    print " ! This city seems to be THE Unknown city"

# Solution 2
if 'No station' in urllib2.urlopen(j.get('url')).read():
    print " ! Again.. This city seems to be THE Unknown city"
```